# How to allow negative value also for 2 decimal limit using angular13

Tags: angular, currency

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g67fwz?file=src/app/app.component.html)
Hi i am using angular13, and here i want to restrict the input field with 2 digit decimal. This is working fine, but this input must allow negative values as well, i have tried with multiple regex patters but didnt work.

HTML:

```
<form  [formGroup]="eoInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Amount <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount in dolars"
            formControlName="amount" autocomplete="off" currencyInput maxDigits="9" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': eoInfo.amount.dirty  && eoInfo.amount.invalid }">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
 private regexString(max?: number) {
    const maxStr = max ? `{0,${max}}` : `+`;
    return `^(\\d${maxStr}(\\.\\d{0,2})?|\\.\\d{0,2})$`
  }
  private digitRegex: RegExp;
  private setRegex(maxDigits?: number) {
    this.digitRegex = new RegExp(this.regexString(maxDigits), 'g')
  }
  @Input()
  set maxDigits(maxDigits: number) {
    this.setRegex(maxDigits);
  } 

  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.setRegex();
  }

  private default = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.default = this.el.value;
    this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value, 'USD');
  }

  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus(value) {
    // on focus remove currency formatting
    this.el.value = value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');
    this.el.select();
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {
    // on blur, add currency formatting
    this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value, 'USD');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-mask

```
npm install --save ngx-mask
```

visit  stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mask-ffmmwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i shouldnt use any plugin for this, with available code i have to make it work, pls help

Comment: can you the directive for same.

Comment: this is not working Rutvik,, my requirement is i must allow both positive and negative values with 2 digit decimal values, but i shouldnt use any plugin

Comment: please visit this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html